# Die Bedeutung des Verbs 'aufhalten'

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Welche Bedeutung hat das Verb "aufhalten" in dem folgenden Satz?

*"Wenn ich die Hand hebe, werde ich eine Granate im Fluge aufhalten"*

Es gibt zwei Möglichkeiten:

1. Er hebt die Hand und fängt die fliegende Granate auf.
2. Er stoppt das Projektil mit einer einzigen Handbewegung, ohne es zu berühren.

Der Satz ist natürlich metaphorisch gemeint :)

Answer (score 4):

Das Verb *aufhalten* selbst besagt nur, dass eine Bewegung beendet wird, aber nicht, auf welche Weise das geschieht. Für den Beispielsatz bedeutet dies, dass die Frage, wie die Granate aufgehalten wird, nicht beantwortet werden kann. Wenn die Information wichtig ist, müsste man sie erwähnen, zum Beispiel so:

- Ich werde die Granate aufhalten, *indem ich sie fange*.
- Ich werde die Granate *durch Schwingen des Zauberstabs* aufhalten.

Comment: Wobei natürlich ein ordentlicher Schwung eines beliebigen Gegenstands Flugbahnen unterbrechen kann ;)

Comment: Das Beispiel *die Hand aufhalten* zeigt eine ganz andere Bedeutung.

Comment: So ein Beispiel habe ich doch gar nicht. In beiden Beispielen wird eine Granate aufgehalten, und nicht die Hand.

Answer (score 1):

Ohne weiteren Kontext ist diese Frage nicht zu beantworten. *»Etwas im Fluge aufhalten«* bedeutet lediglich, dass die Fortbewegung des Flugobjekts gestoppt wird. Physikalisch ist dazu eine Kraft notwendig, die der Bewegungsrichtung entgegenwirkt, aber ob diese Kraft durch Kontakt mit einem festen Körper oder durch entgegenströmende Luft oder durch ein Kraftfeld (z.B. Magnetfeld) übertragen wird, ist unerheblich und ist kein Bestandteil der Aussage *»etwas im Fluge aufhalten«.*

Answer (score 1):

Es kann theoretisch beides sein, aber ich würde es eher als "magically stop" interpretieren.

Wenn gemeint ist, dass man die Granate fängt, dann wäre es ein UNGLAUBLICH komplizierter Weg das zu sagen, und ich sehe keinen Grund, das so verschwurbelt zu formulieren, außer, dass man kein Muttersprachler ist.